# Fleet Server In Elastic Error : elastic-agent-cluster-leader is forbidden

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack, fleet

We are setting up a fleet server in Kubernetes.
It has been given a CA and states its running but we cannot shell into it, and the logs are nothing but the following:

> E0817 09:12:10.074969 927 leaderelection.go:330] error retrieving
> resource lock default/elastic-agent-cluster-leader:
> leases.coordination.k8s.io "elastic-agent-cluster-leader" is
> forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:elastic-agent" cannot
> get resource "leases" in API group "coordination.k8s.io" in the
> namespace "default"

I can find very little information on this ever happening let alone a resolution. Any information pointing to a possible resolution would be massively helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have applied the `ServiceAccount`, `ClusterRoles` and `ClusterRoleBindings` from the setup files.

An example of these can be found in the quickstart documentation.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/2.2/k8s-elastic-agent-fleet-quickstart.html

Service Account

```
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: elastic-agent
  namespace: default
```

Cluster Role

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: elastic-agent
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources:
  - pods
  - nodes
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - get
  - watch
  - list
- apiGroups: ["coordination.k8s.io"]
  resources:
  - leases
  verbs:
  - get
  - create
  - update
```

Cluster Role Binding

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: elastic-agent
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: elastic-agent
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: elastic-agent
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Comment: I came hunting for copper, but found GOLD! Thanks